# Console log json value

Tags: javascript, json, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

I'm working with Testcafe and I would like to ask how to display on the console a json value.
For example, I have this link "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
I want to console the first username or all usernames for example.
Best regards!

Comment: `console.log( JSON.stringify( yourJson , 0, 2))` ?

Comment: Hi @MisterJojo , I tried this and it's not working
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')   
.then(response => response.json())   
.then(json => console.log(json))

console.log( JSON.stringify( JSON[0].username))

Comment: to obtain the data here, you need to install and run json server. are you sure you did that ? you never mentioned it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try    with {}

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
 .then(resp => resp.json()) 
 .then(data => {
   console.log( JSON.stringify( data , 0, 2))
   })
```

> to only usernames

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
 .then(resp => resp.json()) 
 .then(data =>
  {
  data.forEach(el=>console.log(el.username) )
  })
```

Comment: I got this error
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(value: any, replacer?: (this: any, key: string, value: any) => any, space?: string | number): string', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '0' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: any, key: string, value: any) => any'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(value: any, replacer?: (string | number)[], space?: string | number): string', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '0' is not assignable to parameter of type '(string | number)[]'.

Comment: @MohamedKhlifi try again, you forget to add http

Comment: It worked and I changed the last line to "console.log( JSON.stringify(data[0].username))" to get the first username. Do you have an idea how to loop through all username to add an if-condition? I will need it.

Comment: @MohamedKhlifi  just added this case on my post

Answer (score 1):

The code given is an array of objects. You can use an inbuilt javascript array method, forEach() to filter through each object in the array. The forEach() method takes a function as a parameter that you can specify what you want to happen for each item in the array, in your example, log the unsername of the object.

```
console.log(string.forEach(obj =>{
    console.log(obj.username);
 })
);
```

You can read about this more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused with how your JSON object is setup in the link that you presented. If all of your objects that are shown in that link are held in an array (most likely) then you'll want to do something like this

```
yourJson.forEach(object => {console.log(object.username)})
```

Comment: Hi, I tried Response.forEach(object => {console.log(object.username)}) and I got this error
 Property 'forEach' does not exist on type '{ new (body?: BodyInit, init?: ResponseInit): Response; prototype: Response; error(): Response; redirect(url: string, status?: number): Response; }'.

Comment: if you `console.log(typeof Response)` what do you get?

Comment: This is what I typed fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')   
.then(response => response.json())   
.then(json => console.log(json))

console.log(typeof Response)
I got "function" and the whole json displayed